# performance of Typed arrays vs Non typed arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Learning about typed arrays, I read typed arrays normally should be more efficient/performant than non-typed ones.

I run this simple test (replace a for b to run each test):

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const b = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4])

const compare1 = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) arr[i]
}

let run = 0

const init1 = performance.now()

while (run < 10e7) {
  compare1(a)
  run++
}

const finish1 = performance.now()
console.log("for a ", finish1 - init1)

const compare2 = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) arr[i]
}

run = 0
const init2 = performance.now()

while (run < 10e7) {
  compare2(b)
  run++
}

const finish2 = performance.now()

console.log("for b ", finish2 - init2)
```

array contains mixed string and number types.

But maybe I am not getting some idea here...

Should those be expected to differ more? Example?

---

**Edit**: Added 2 different compareX functions.

Comment: Should differ more than what? Could you share any results, please?

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets included runnable snippet

Comment: a) typed arrays are more memory efficient only for larger sizes b) don't use mixed-type arrays, they're always slow c) running the *same* `compare` function with multiple types of arrays will make it slow, especially on second run, regardless of which run is which type d) your `compare` function is a [meaningless microbenchmark](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html)